# iOS direct install from within an app

Tags: ios, app-store, installation

I just clicked on an ad banner in an iOS app. An interstitial (a layer above the actual app) opened and I was able to install the app without being redirected to the app store. This is what happened:

1. Click on banner ad
2. Interstitial opens full screen
3. I clicked a button with "Play now" on it (on the interstitial)
4. I was not redirected to the app store but was able to use touch id in order to directly download the app from within the interstitial

I have two questions regarding this user experience:

1. How is this done?
2. Is this also possible from within safari or a webpage in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take a look at the [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html)
2. No, but you can link to the page on the app store and it should automatically open in the App Store app if running on an iOS device. I suppose one could also implement a browser that redirects app store links to a SKStoreProductViewControoller.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But just to be clear, the user must not be redirected/switched to the "App Store" app itself but start the installation right out of safari . How do I do that?

Comment: Don't think that is supported in Safari.

Comment: Well then, your answer to question 2 is not correct. It should be updated to "No".